# Universal link redirect me to the safari instead of my app in iOS 13

Tags: swift, xcode, swift5, xcode11.3

I am implementing Universal link to my app.My problem is when I press link take me to safari and show my pop up screen ask me to downlaod  apple -app-site-asscoiation instead of open the app, I am using real device not the simulator

this is the link

https://emd.digitom.mosaic-dev.siemens.cloud/.well-known/apple-app-site-association

[image]

- this is my associated domains

[image]

- apple -app-site-asscoiation

  ```
   {
      "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
        {
          "appID": "Teamid.Bunduleid",
          "paths": ["digitom-password-reset/*","digitom-confirm-email/*"]
        }
        ]
      }
    }
  ```
- APP delegate code

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to click that link to just open your app. That link is what Apple requires on your site to let the system know when to open your app and when to open the browser. As I see, your current allowed paths do not contain the link you are trying to click, so opening Safari is expected behavior. You should try with this link first:

https://emd.digitom.mosaic-dev.siemens.cloud/digitom-password-reset

Comment: ok I will try this solution, and I will tell you feedback